# django-axes not capturing failed login attempt on RPC

Tags: python, django, authentication, axes

I use django-axes to capture the failed login but I thing this library uses the internal DB of django and my case the authentication is a RPC call. The code is:

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', watch_login(views.login.as_view()),name='login')
```

views.py

```
class login(Base):

def __init__(self):
    Base.__init__(self) 



def get(self, request):

        return render(request, 'templates/login.html', {'menu':self.menu})

@method_decorator(watch_login) 
def post(self,request):


        response = self.server.login(request.POST['username'],request.POST['password'])
        if(response['correct']==True):
            request.session['session_id']=response['sessionid']
            request.session['response']=response
            request.session.set_expiry(5)
            request.session['username']=request.POST['username']

            return redirect(reverse('home:IndexHome')) 
        else:


            return redirect(reverse('login'))
```

I don't know where the library caught the fail logins and I try a lot of variants to solve this trouble.

PD: I changed my settings.py too.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
return render(request,'templates/login.html',status=302)
```

instead of

```
return redirect(reverse('login'))
```